# Elasticsearch sorting by relationship

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I've defined relationship like this

```
PUT /my_index/user/1 
{
  "name":     "John Smith",
  "email":    "john@smith.com",
  "dob":      "1970/10/24"
  "number_of_posts": 4
}

PUT /my_index/blogpost/2 
{
  "title":    "Relationships",
  "body":     "It's complicated...",
  "user":     1 
}
```

How can I sort blogpost by user information like name, email or number_of_posts without using nested field on blogpost, because I don't want to update all blogpost with user = 1 when user change their information. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a database for persistence or just Elasticsearch?

Comment: both of them (mysql and ES), Because I've many field search (not only simple like this) So can not using mysql to sort.